# Как сделать высокочастотный фильтр? - C#

Tags: c#, .net

Если при создание низкочастотного я использовал класс ComplexImage
  Мне нужно сделать что бы изображение получалось как на фильтре, только на оборот где было черное стало белое и наоборот. 
Заранее благодарю.

```
// create complex image
ComplexImage complexImage = ComplexImage.FromBitmap( image );
// do forward Fourier transformation
complexImage.ForwardFourierTransform( );
// get complex image as bitmat
Bitmap fourierImage = complexImage.ToBitmap( );
```

[image: Исходное изображенние]
[image: Фильтр]

Comment: А откуда вы взяли этот класс `ComplexImage`? Сами написали, т.е. из собственной головы?

Comment: Нет скачал на сайте http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/8ec218c8-628b-e6b9-c398-3d65f14280d5.htm , я думал существует уже готовое решение моей проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4b1934b5-d0ec-e118-0406-61f161e15ba1.htm) есть пример частотного фильтра.

```
// create complex image
ComplexImage complexImage = ComplexImage.FromBitmap( image );
// do forward Fourier transformation
complexImage.ForwardFourierTransform( );
// create filter
FrequencyFilter filter = new FrequencyFilter( new IntRange( 20, 128 ) );
// apply filter
filter.Apply( complexImage );
// do backward Fourier transformation
complexImage.BackwardFourierTransform( );
// get complex image as bitmat
Bitmap fourierImage = complexImage.ToBitmap( );
```